# Make an Array Display In assignment PHP syntax

Tags: php

Currently, print_r($myarray); return this style of output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

How can this be displayed in a declaration-like syntax? i.e.:

```
$myarray = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to view it in such format? Besides, if you just do `print_r($myArray)` without the `<pre>` tags it will show it like you want it,

Comment: Well I think it would be easier to read in order to understand and extend the contents of a variable, specially for a newcomer of some framework

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where the latter format you specified is in any way better than the first one.

Comment: I recently had to add an element to a very complicated and deep global array. It was actually difficult to follow the print_r tree to figure out the key names and precedence. Using this format you can just copy paste, and switch the last key for the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need this, but you can strigify the array with a simple PHP function

```
function stringify_array($array, $depth=0)
{
    $string = "";
    if (is_array($array))
    {
        $string .= "array (";
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $string .= "'$key' => ";
            $string .= (is_array($value)) ? stringify_array($value, ++$depth) : "'$value'";
            $string .= ",";

        }
        $string .= ")";
        if ($depth == 0)
        {
            $string .= ";";
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

$myarray = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
echo stringify_array($myarray);
```

A working copy can be seen here - http://ideone.com/El1HQu.
Don't mind the trailing commas, they won't rise any errors or notices.